# c# LoadXml randomly return they are several root element without any obvious reasons

Tags: c#, xml, load, root

I am currently developing some solution based on communication through httpwebrequest between some distant (Prestashop) MYSQL database and return on information.

The concept is working like a charm, and I use to load some object, like customers, groups or products through a build Xml response, I de-serialized. All object return same kind of process and all are loading perfectly.
But in case of the products, I recently faced  a mysterious bug, saying that my xml contains several root element, witch is completely wrong. I feel very at ease with Xml building, so I became crazy not finding a way out.
The c# function who operate de serialization is quite simple :

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> get(IRestResponse response)
{
   var objectToLoad = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.LoadXml(response.Content.ToString());
   XmlNodeList idNodes = doc.SelectNodes("object");
   foreach (XmlNode node1 in idNodes)
   {
       foreach (XmlNode node in node1.ChildNodes)
       {
           objectToLoad.Add(node.Name, node.InnerText);
       }
   }
   return objectToLoad;
}
```

To illustrate It, here is a first example loading a group who is working perfectly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
    <id>4</id>
    <reduction>0</reduction>
    <price_display_method>0</price_display_method>
    <show_prices>1</show_prices>
    <date_add>2014-09-23 16:23:05</date_add>
    <date_upd>2014-10-14 09:27:09</date_upd>
    <name>Public VIP</name>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
</object>
```

But when I load a Object type product :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
    <id>6</id>
    <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default>
    <id_manufacturer>1</id_manufacturer>
    <id_supplier>1</id_supplier>
    <reference>MTDENIMJR</reference>
    <supplier_reference></supplier_reference>
    <location></location>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
    <depth>0</depth>
    <weight>0.05</weight>
    <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount>
    <ean13>815264500995</ean13>
    <upc>815264500995</upc>
    <cache_is_pack>0</cache_is_pack>
    <cache_has_attachments>0</cache_has_attachments>
    <is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
    <id_category_default>9</id_category_default>
    <id_tax_rules_group>1</id_tax_rules_group>
    <on_sale>1</on_sale>
    <online_only>0</online_only>
    <ecotax>0</ecotax>
    <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
    <price>10.313</price>
    <wholesale_price>2.9</wholesale_price>
    <unity></unity>
    <unit_price_ratio>0</unit_price_ratio>
    <additional_shipping_cost>0</additional_shipping_cost>
    <customizable>0</customizable>
    <text_fields>0</text_fields>
    <uploadable_files>0</uploadable_files>
    <active>1</active>
    <redirect_type>404</redirect_type>
    <id_product_redirected>0</id_product_redirected>
    <available_for_order>1</available_for_order>
    <available_date>0000-00-00</available_date>
    <condition>new</condition>
    <show_price>1</show_price>
    <indexed>1</indexed>
    <visibility>both</visibility>
    <cache_default_attribute>0</cache_default_attribute>
    <advanced_stock_management>0</advanced_stock_management>
    <date_add>2013-02-27 08:03:35</date_add>
    <date_upd>2018-05-09 10:59:40</date_upd>
    <pack_stock_type>3</pack_stock_type>
    <groups_allowed></groups_allowed>
    <flashsale>0</flashsale>
    <id_google_category>36</id_google_category>
    <meta_description>Vernis à Ongle Morgan Taylor Denim Du Jour Format 15 ml</meta_description>
    <meta_keywords>vernis à ongles,morgantaylor,manucure,beauté des mains,nails,harmony</meta_keywords>
    <meta_title></meta_title>
    <link_rewrite>morgan-taylor-denim-du-jour</link_rewrite>
    <name>Morgan Taylor Denim Du Jour</name>
    <description>&lt;p&gt;Vernis à Ongle Morgan Taylor Denim Du Jour 15 ml&lt;/p&gt;</description>
    <description_short></description_short>
    <available_now></available_now>
    <available_later></available_later>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
</object>
```

I get with this products and all other a System.Xml.XmlException: 'They are several root element. Line 2, position 2.'

There is only one root element : "object", and each nodes are unique, I have been trying to all online Xml checker, my return Xml pass every test successfully,so I just turn a little crazy.

So if there are some good soul who would maybe give me a suggestion, or a beginning of explanation, or simply point to my attention a huge mistake I am doing, I would highly appreciate It :)

Million of thanks in advance !

Jeff

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: VS 2017 Enterprise give a very poor info :Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: Can't replicate the error on my machine, using your code + the second XML you provided. Are you sure the content string is exactly the same as the XML you posted here? There might be an encoding issue?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the empty nodes that you have: <description_short></description_short>

Comment: System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)\r\n   à System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)\r\n

Comment: Yes that strictly the same code as I paste It from a console.writeline from output VS panel. I am going to try to find some other items who's description_short are not empty.

Comment: Solved !!!!! For some reason beyond my understanding, I put the web site in debug mode to take a look at the server logs more accurately ! After removing the debug mode, All came suddenly back to normal !! Thanks to all of you for your concerns ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake went from linux Server side due to ** `@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`**
Everything is rolling great again !

Thanks for all your concerns and support !

Jeff